# Is it possible to extend the notion of $H$-convergence to the case of distributions?

Tags: convergence-divergence, asymptotics, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, weak-convergence

The usual $H$-convergence is defined for operators of the following form (for the sake of simplicity, restrict ourselves with the one-dimensional case):
$$
\frac{d}{d x}\left[A_\varepsilon(x) \frac{d w_\varepsilon}{dx}\right] = f,
$$
where $A_\varepsilon$ is usually assumed to be an $L^\infty$ function (with some additional constraints), $w_\varepsilon \in H^1$ and $f \in H^{-1}$ is a distribution. Then, $A_\varepsilon$ is said to be $H$-convergent to an $A_0 \in L^\infty$, if and only if
$$
w_\varepsilon \to w_0 ~~ as ~~ \varepsilon \to 0 ~~ weakly ~~ in ~~ H^1,
$$
$$
A_\varepsilon \frac{d w_\varepsilon}{d x} \to A_0 \frac{d w_0}{d x} ~~ as ~~ \varepsilon \to 0 ~~ weakly ~~ in ~~ L^2.
$$
Here $w_0$ is the solution of
$$
\frac{d}{d x}\left[A_0(x) \frac{d w_0}{dx}\right] = f.
$$

I am interested if this concept can be generalized to be valid for $A_\varepsilon$ which converges to $A_0$ in the sense of distributions, i.e., for any compactly supported smooth function $\varphi$,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty A_\varepsilon(x) \varphi(x) dx \to \int_{-\infty}^\infty A_0(x) \varphi(x) dx ~~ as ~~ \varepsilon \to 0?
$$

Comment: it is not entirely clear what your question is. $H$-convergence defines a convergence of $A_\varepsilon$ to $A_0$. If you already have convergence of $A_\epsilon$ to $A_0$ (in a sense of distributions, as you consider), then the question one can ask may concern the comparison of the two modes of convergence, say if one regime implies the other or not... Generalizing as you define, might be understood as starting from convergence in distribution, and checking if that is also $H$-convergent, which will not lead too far. Anyway, you should try to clarify what you mean by generalization.

Comment: As a quick remark, I think there is little relevance between $H$-convergence, and convergence in distribtion. For instance, if $A$ is smooth and $1$-periodic, and if one defines $A_\varepsilon (x)=A(x/\varepsilon)$ then $A_\varepsilon $ converges weakly (as a distribution) to its integral over its cell of periodicity (this is $A_0$, a constant) However, this constant is (in general) quite different from the $A_0$ of the $H$-convergence which would correspond to the homogenized operator (see Tartar's book on homogenization, for example). These two $A_0$-s, although both constant, are different.

Comment: @Hayk jan, in the definition of $H$-convergence, Tartar assumes that both $A_\varepsilon$ and its $H$-limit $A_0$ are from $L^\infty$. My question is: what if $A_\varepsilon$ converges to $A_0$ not in $L^\infty$, but, for instance, in $H^{-1}$? Will this still imply $w_\varepsilon \to w_0$ (weakly) as $\varepsilon \to 0$ or not?

Comment: in general, $A_\varepsilon$ does not converge to $A_0$ in $L^\infty$, except for trivial cases. As a good model to keep in mind, think of $A_\varepsilon (x) = A(x/\varepsilon)$, where $A(x)$ is smooth and (say) $1$-periodic.
In homogenization of the first equation in your question, it is not that you prove convergence (in some standard metric) of $A_\varepsilon$ to $A_0$, but rather you aim to find an $A_0$ such that there will be convergence of the solutions of the $\varepsilon$ problem to the one with $A_0$.

Comment: It's hardly possible that you'll find convergence of $A_\varepsilon$ to $A_0$ in some traditional metric. Think of $A_\varepsilon$ from the perspective of homogenization. It's not that you base on the assumption of convergence of $A_\varepsilon$ to $A_0$ and then go for the solutions, but quite the contrary: you determine $A_0$ so that to get convergence between solutions. Even with $H$-convergence, there is no direct relation between $A_\varepsilon$ and $A_0$ (say convergence in some metric). What you get is that $A_0$ captures the averaging effect of the microstructure of the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the answer to my question! You can post it as an answer, so I will be able to accept it.

Comment: In my case, $A_\varepsilon \in L^\infty$, while $A_0 \in H^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What follows is an expansion of the comments made above earlier.
In general, there is little to no relevance between homogenization of the equation $$
\tag{1} - \frac{d}{dx} \left(A_\varepsilon (x) \frac{d w_\varepsilon(x) }{dx}  \right) = f
$$
and the actual convergence between $A_\varepsilon$ to $A_0$ (in some metric, for instance).

The model case, to keep in mind is the case of periodic homogenization, when one assumes that $A:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is $C^\infty$ and $1$-periodic, i.e. $A(x + h) = A(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and any $h \in \mathbb{Z}$, and then defines $A_\varepsilon (x) = A(x/ \varepsilon)$.

Assuming $A$ to be elliptic, and setting the problem $(1)$ in some interval $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $f\in L^1(a, b)$ and $w_\varepsilon \in H^1_0(a,b)$ ($0$-boundary data)  it is a well-known fact (see any book on homogenization of PDEs, for instance [the classics](https://books.google.am/books/about/Asymptotic_Analysis_for_Periodic_Structu.html?id=ADNwAdxvEK0C&redir_esc=y)) that 
$$
A_0 = \frac{1}{ \int\limits_0^1 \frac{dx}{A(x)} }.
$$ 
Notice, that we are in 1d and ellipticity condition on $A$ forces $A>0$.

So, we have that $A_\varepsilon$ converges to $\int\limits_0^1 A(x) dx$ weak* in $L^\infty$ (this is not hard to see, using for example the Fourier series expansion of $A$), however the actual homogenized coefficient $A_0$ is different from the weak limit of $A_\varepsilon$.

The point being made in the model case discussed above, is that one should think about the convergence business related to $A_\varepsilon$ from the perspective of homogenization: you do not aim to find $A_0$ to which $A_\varepsilon$ actually converges, but rather you find $A_0$ from the condition that the entire problem $(1)$ "converges" to the one with coefficient $A_0$. That is, there is a convergence of the solutions of $\varepsilon$-problem to the one with homogenized coefficients. In particular the $H$-convergence you mentioned, refers to the homogenization of the problem $(1)$ and does not necessarily imply direct convergence of coefficients $A_\varepsilon$ to $A_0$ in any standard metric.